# How to configure Google Sign in on Android sans email/password webview

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin, google-smartlockpasswords

I have code similar to that of [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#configure_google_sign-in_and_the_googleapiclient_object) official guide for Google Sign in. When my users click the sign in button and then select a local google profile to log in with, it directs them to the email/password webview. Despite the presence of forced logins, I do have a perfect google login flow that runs parallel with my Facebook login.

Is there a more simple way to take care of this so that I can get the **name, email, and token** from local Google accounts without being forced to use the Google Sign In Email/Password UI?

I have seen and clicked on the user profiles that if offers me, but the clicks open the web view which asks for email/password.

Here is some code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode("myauthcode")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                       .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: If you're following the [sign in guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) you say you are, users should most definitely be able to select an account on their device. I'd suggest getting that fixed first - show your code.

Comment: I modified my post. Clicking my google login button opens an account selector. Selecting an account leads to the webview. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Auth.CREDENTIALS_API`, you'll be going through the : [Smart Lock integration flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/overview).

Which for users which do not have any credentials or have specifically signed out, goes through a sign-in/sign-up flow to create a new account with your service:

[image: Smart Lock integration]

If you **don't** have your own sign in flow, then you shouldn't be using the `CREDENTIALS_API`. Instead, only use the `GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` and the name, email, and token that you can retrieve with that.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to get a login token, name, and email without forcing the user to physically enter their credentials into the email/password form?

Comment: @user2355058 - that's exactly what the [sign-in guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) does.

Comment: Thanks for the back and forth. I like your videos. Then I wonder what is causing the form to open up after clicking my google profile on the selection screen? Maybe I should just retry the sign-in guide?

Comment: There's also a [sign in sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) which you could try and compare your app to.

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution to my problem is surely there.

Comment: Still not working despite seeming to be identical to the authCodeActivity from the sample that you linked. When I click the Google Sign-in Button, it shows the profile selector. When the profiles are clicked the email/password form is presented again. On a side note, silentsignin does work if I put it behind the login button or in the oncreate of my loginfragment. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I narrowed down the problem. It turns out that the form is actually just appears at random times. Clicking the profile does indeed initiate my login flow, but the form comes up anyway until I dismiss it with the back button! weird, Im sure I can figure it out.